# How to improve input image for more correct results - pytesseract

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I am making an app which requires to be as accurate as possible. I know that I have to improve the input image so the output is more accurate, but I am not sure which setting would be the best.

[image]

For example, if I use `image_to_sting('the image above', lang='ces')`,

the result is `'TAL8911\n'`,

but obviously I expect it to be `'7AL8911\n'` or ideally `'7AL8911'`.

How can I improve the image or what config should I use for tesseract?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'd make sure to go through and understand all the suggestions from Tesseract https://tesseract-ocr.github.io/tessdoc/ImproveQuality.html

Comment: That link from @ti7 is excellent and specifically for this image, you might need to add extra border, and you might try different `psm` values.